# How to reflect Firebase Event Listener changes to a DIV element inside a web page

Tags: javascript, java, firebase, firebase-admin

I have setup Firebase admin sdk for java and have used it inside a Servlet.

I have setup a valueeventlistener on a node where the value keeps changing. I wish to show the changed value inside the Div element in the HTML page that I have printed out.

Here is the code that I have tried, The value gets printed to the console but the value is not shown inside the DIV element.

I do not know anything about AJAX and only have limited knowledge of javascript. Kindly help me to show the value.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseCredentials;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

@WebServlet("/WebWaitlistViewServelet")
public class WebWaitlistViewServelet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public WebWaitlistViewServelet() {
    super();
}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();

    try {

        String cityName=request.getParameter("city");

        String restId = request.getParameter("restid");

        String userId = request.getParameter("userid");

        if(cityName == null || restId == null || userId == null){
            System.out.println("Error getting values");
            return;
        }else{
            System.out.println(cityName+" "+restId+" "+userId);
        }


        pw.println("<HTML>");

            pw.println("<HEAD>");

                pw.println("<TITLE>Your current position in the waitlist is:</TITLE>");

            pw.println("</HEAD>");

            pw.println("<BODY>");

                pw.println("<DIV id=\"test\" align=\"center\">");

                pw.println("</DIV><br/>");

            pw.println("<BODY>");

        pw.println("</HTML>");

        pw.flush();


        InputStream is = getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/firebaseauth/firebase_admin_sdk_key.json");

        // Initialize the app with a service account, granting admin privileges
        FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setCredential(FirebaseCredentials.fromCertificate(is))
            .setDatabaseUrl("https://restaurantrepo.firebaseio.com")
            .build();
        try {
            FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //
        }



        // As an admin, the app has access to read and write all data, regardless of Security Rules
        DatabaseReference waitlistRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(cityName).child(restId).child("waitlist");

        ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener(){

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                System.out.println("Sorry. some error occured");
            }

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {



                if(dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()==1 || dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() == 0 ){
                    System.out.println("You are no longer in the waitlist");
                }else
                    pw.println("<script>document.getElementById('test').innerHTML= '"+dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class)+"' </script>");

                    System.out.println("the changed value is "+dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class));

                }

            }

        };

        waitlistRef.addValueEventListener(eventListener);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        try {
            pw.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //do nothing here
        }
    }


}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    doGet(request, response);
}

}
```

Comment: Don't report the same question. If you're not getting help, update your original question to improve the chance of getting help. A good way to do so is by reducing the code to the [minimum that is needed to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Does it really need all of the technologies you have now? Or would you also be stuck if this was only in JavaScript? Does it really need to be a servlet? Or can it also be in any Java program? The smaller the code, the easier it will be to help, so the more likely somebody will be able to help.

Comment: Sorry frank, i thought making it simpler with less logic would help people answer. Anyway... It does not need to be a servlet. Problem is, i m not much of a server side tech guy, i am an android dev so don't know much about other tech. I am looking into making this a nodejs app now. Looks simpler that way but i have never used that before. I'll try that out.

Comment: Reducing the code may help getting an answer. But you can edit your original question to do so.